# Deserialize XML to Nested Objects in symfony 2.8

Tags: xml, symfony, serialization, xml-deserialization

Following xml format

```
<fraud_report_responses per_page="100" page="2" total_count="19" pages_count="7">
<fraud_report_response>
<arn>74537604221431003881865</arn>
<transaction_date>2014-01-24</transaction_date>
<fraud_type_code>6</fraud_type_code>
<amount>14625</amount>
<currency>USD</currency>
<card_number>554960******5069</card_number>
<card_brand>master</card_brand>
<customer_email>emil@e-comprocessing.net</customer_email>
<customer_phone>3598851248512</customer_phone>
<transaction_type>sale3d</transaction_type>
<original_transaction_unique_id>f9634ec5e7dbe6ca3871974accb875cd</original_transaction_unique_id>
<original_merchant_transaction_id>f9634ec5e7d5cd</original_merchant_transaction_id>
</fraud_report_response>
<fraud_report_response>
<arn>74537604221431003881862</arn>
<transaction_date>2014-01-27</transaction_date>
<fraud_type_code>4</fraud_type_code>
<amount>3456</amount>
<currency>EUR</currency>
<card_number>454360******5008</card_number>
<card_brand>visa</card_brand>
<customer_email>ivan@e-comprocessing.net</customer_email>
<customer_phone>3598851248123</customer_phone>
<transaction_type>sale</transaction_type>
<original_transaction_unique_id>67fbebc172b743a164a3f3af3d010457</original_transaction_unique_id>
<original_merchant_transaction_id>67fbebc172b743a164a3f3af3d010457</original_merchant_transaction_id>
</fraud_report_response>
</fraud_report_responses>
```

I was created entity class for store data in doctrine entity
Below code of entity class

```
class Genesisapicall
{

/**
    * @var int
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var string
 */
private $arn;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $typeCode;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $currency;

/**
 * @var int
 */
private $amount;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $cardBrand;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $customerEmail;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $customerPhone;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $transactionDate;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $transactionType;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $referenceId;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set arn
 *
 * @param string $arn
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setArn($arn)
{
    $this->arn = $arn;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get arn
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getArn()
{
    return $this->arn;
}

/**
 * Set typeCode
 *
 * @param string $typeCode
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setTypeCode($typeCode)
{
    $this->typeCode = $typeCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get typeCode
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTypeCode()
{
    return $this->typeCode;
}

/**
 * Set currency
 *
 * @param string $currency
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setCurrency($currency)
{
    $this->currency = $currency;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get currency
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrency()
{
    return $this->currency;
}

/**
 * Set amount
 *
 * @param integer $amount
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setAmount($amount)
{
    $this->amount = $amount;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get amount
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getAmount()
{
    return $this->amount;
}

/**
 * Set cardBrand
 *
 * @param string $cardBrand
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setCardBrand($cardBrand)
{
    $this->cardBrand = $cardBrand;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cardBrand
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCardBrand()
{
    return $this->cardBrand;
}

/**
 * Set customerEmail
 *
 * @param string $customerEmail
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setCustomerEmail($customerEmail)
{
    $this->customerEmail = $customerEmail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get customerEmail
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomerEmail()
{
    return $this->customerEmail;
}

/**
 * Set customerPhone
 *
 * @param string $customerPhone
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setCustomerPhone($customerPhone)
{
    $this->customerPhone = $customerPhone;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get customerPhone
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomerPhone()
{
    return $this->customerPhone;
}

/**
 * Set transactionDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $transactionDate
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setTransactionDate($transactionDate)
{
    $this->transactionDate = $transactionDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get transactionDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getTransactionDate()
{
    return $this->transactionDate;
}

/**
 * Set transactionType
 *
 * @param string $transactionType
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setTransactionType($transactionType)
{
    $this->transactionType = $transactionType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get transactionType
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTransactionType()
{
    return $this->transactionType;
}

/**
 * Set referenceId
 *
 * @param string $referenceId
 *
 * @return Genesisapicall
 */
public function setReferenceId($referenceId)
{
    $this->referenceId = $referenceId;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * Get referenceId
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReferenceId()
{
    return $this->referenceId;


 }
}
```

When I try to deserialize it, I get the following result:

```
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $person = $serializer->deserialize($data,'GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall','xml');
        var_dump($person);
```

Response

```
object(GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall)#221 (11) { ["id":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
 ["arn":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
 ["typeCode":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
["currency":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL 
["amount":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
 ["cardBrand":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
 ["customerEmail":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
 ["customerPhone":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
 ["transactionDate":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL
 ["transactionType":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL 
["referenceId":"GenesisapicallBundle\Entity\Genesisapicall":private]=> NULL 
}
```

So there are 1 issues:
1) How can deserialize xml data with multiple attrubute or inline XML list?

Any ideas how to make it work without manual deserialization in a handler?

Comment: How about a minimal example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve